# Extend form of java class

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, extending

I used Intellij IDEA and have a `BaseClickPanel.java` and form to it `BaseClickPanel.form` which is designed by GUI Intellij editor.

In `BaseClickPanel` I got two buttons - `startButton` and `targetButton`.

```
public class BaseClickPanel {
    protected JButton startButton;
    private JButton targetButton;

    public BaseClickPanel() {
        targetButton.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            //do one thing
        });
    }
```

I create other GUI Form - `NativeClickPanel` which extends `BaseClickPanel` and do only one thing - add action listener in constructor as below:

```
public class NativeClickPanel extends BaseClickPanel {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public NativeClickPanel() {
        startButton.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            //do something else
        });
    }
}
```

I need to extend the `BaseClickPanel` because I used `JTabbedPane` and there I want have many Tabs which view looks the same but action in buttons click must be different.

And there is my problem, it means that when I add action listener in `BaseClickPanel` to `targetButton` it work well but when I try to add action listener to `startButton` in class `NativeClickPanel` it do not work - it looks as it try to add this listener but do not add. Can someone explain me this why ?

Comment: You need to call `super()` in the constructor of `NativeClickPanel`

Comment: @MuratK.: regarding, `"You need to call super() in the constructor of NativeClickPanel "` -- and how will that benefit in any way possible? Super constructors are *always* called either explicitly or implicitly. And in fact the default constructor is already being called implicitly. Calling it explicitly will accomplish nothing of benefit.

Comment: Original poster: you need to tell and show more. How are you running your code? And mostly -- why are you trying to use inheritance for something that should not be solved with inheritance?

Comment: Adding `super()` do not help. I debug and checked did there are any listener added to `startButton` but there is no one.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I need extend it because want change only one thing - what is executed by clicking in button in different views. I do not want duplicate code which the save views, fields and buttons.

Comment: But you don't use inheritance to solve this. Instead you give BaseClickPanel a method that allows outside code to add ActionListeners to your buttons, and then create an instance of this class. Inheritance is not the best tool for this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I edit my post. I used JTabbedPane with the same views (buttons) but other action of them.

Comment: We'll need to see a valid [mcve] / [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to be able to answer without guessing.